# show the result is right when $f\in C(\Bbb{R})$, but when $f$ is only Riemann integrable. Is it right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume $f(x) \in C(\Bbb{R})$, and $$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right),n=1,2,\cdots,$$
show that: $\forall [a,b] \subset \Bbb{R}$ ,  $S_n$ converges uniformly

and if $f(x)$ is only Riemann integrable in any closed subset of $\Bbb{R}$, can we prove the above result or give a counter-example?

Comment: Note that, $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x+t) dt .$

Answer (score 1):

Let's note that for any given x in [a,b] and for any given natural n, we can divide the section [x,x+1] in the following manner:
$ \pi =[x,x+\frac{1}{n}, x+\frac{2}{n},....x+\frac{n}{n}]$, such that we can calculate f's Riemann sum (this is possible because f is continuous) in the following manner:

For every section $ [x+\frac{k-1}{n}, x+\frac{k}{n}]$ for $ k \in [1, n]$, we can choose the fitting point to be $ f(x+\frac{k}{n})$, and since f is integrable, then, the Riemann sum $ S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}f(x+\frac{k}{n}) $ must converge uniformly to f's integral in [a,b], meaning, $ S_n(x) \rightarrow \int _a ^x f(t)dt$